# Is "\" an unfinished string? Why can't I use print("\")?

Tags: lua

The question is simple. I just tried to print the `\` character using this code:

```
print("\")
```

But an error has occurred saying that it's an unfinished string.

I'm using Lua 5.2 version.

Comment: It's treating it as an escape character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Backslashes are used for escape sequences, you should print 2 backslashes, like this:

`print("\\")`

See [this](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.4.html) for more details on escaping strings, and just strings in general.